# AngularJS: Why scope variable usage is different in directive and in regular controller?

Tags: angularjs

I am following an angular book. In one chapter it is showing how to use directive:

```
angular.module("cart", [])
.factory("cart", function() {
    var cartData = [];

    return {
        addProduct: function(id, name, price) {
            var addedToExistingItem = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < cartData.length; i++) {
                if (cartData[i].id == id) {
                    cartData[i].count++;
                    addedToExistingItem = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!addedToExistingItem) {
                cartData.push({
                    count: 1, id: id, price: price, name: name
                });
            }
        },

        removeProduct: function(id) {
            for (var i = 0; i < cartData.length; i++) {
                if (cartData[i].id == id) {
                    cartData.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        },

        getProducts: function() {
            return cartData;
        }
    }
})
.directive("cartSummary", function(cart) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "components/cart/cartSummary.html",
        controller: function ($scope) {
            var cartData = cart.getProducts();

            $scope.total = function() {
                var total = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < cartData.length; i++) {
                    total += (cartData[i].price * cartData[i].count);
                }

                return total;
            }

            $scope.itemCount = function() {
                var total = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < cartData.length; i++) {
                    total += cartData[i].count;
                }

                return total;
            }
        }

    }
});
```

In cartSummary.html, it shows how to use the itemCount and total:

```
<style>
    .navbar-right { float: right !important; margin-right: 5px;}
    .navbar-text { margin-right: 10px;}
</style>

<div class="navbar-right">
    <div class="navbar-text">
        <b>Your cart:</b>
        {{itemCount()}} item(s),
        {{total() | currency}}
    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Checkout</a>
</div>
```

I had an impression that when I define a scope variable in controller, I can render the value in the view by using the double brace. However, looks like the controller in the directive seems different. It requires a () in order to render a scope variable value.

I am just wondering what is the magic behind this?

Thanks.

Comment: In one case you're rendering the output of a function which is defined on the scope. And in the other, you are rendering a variable on the scope.

Answer (score 0):

the `()` is a function call.  So if you want to render a response form a function it would look like this:

```
{{ function() }}
```

If you are rendering a value it would look like this:

```
{{ value }}
```

The best way to bind a value in my opinion is to use `ng-bind`:

```
<div ng-bind="value"></div>
<div ng-bind="function()"></div>
```

Because this avoids the FOUC (flash of unstyled content) where you could potentially see `{{ value }}` rendered for a couple seconds before angular binds the value.

Hope this helps.